# Returning record ID's from PostgreSQL using PetaPoco

Tags: postgresql, petapoco

PetaPoco PostgreSQL 11.1

I am attempting to get a list of deleted record id's. This does NOT work:

```
var sql = new Sql()
      .Append(@"; WITH _in (lastname, firstname, birthdate, description, dencounter) AS (
                  VALUES ( UPPER(@0), UPPER(@1), @2::date, LOWER(@3), @4::date  )
                       )
                   DELETE FROM dx d
                    USING _in n
                   JOIN patients pt ON (pt.lastname, pt.firstname, pt.birthdate) = (n.lastname, n.firstname, n.birthdate)
                  JOIN disease z ON (z.description = n.description)
                  WHERE (d.patient_recid, d.disease_recid, d.dposted)=(pt.recid, z.recid, n.dencounter)
               RETURNING d.recid;", lastName, firstName, birthDate, description, tencounter);

      return db.Fetch<int?>(sql);
```

The RETURNING is not being honored. (I receive the "1" showing Delete success not the recid value). It runs correctly in pgAdmin 4.

Is there anyway to do this with PetaPoco (and C#) ? I am looking not just for a single recid, but an IEnumerable of int? from many deletions.

TIA

Comment: What does `db.ExecuteScalar<int?>(sql)` return?

Comment: @Plebsori db.ExecuteScalar<int?> correctly returns a single recid -- but I need all the recid's. (Does ExecuteScalar only return the first column of the first row?).

Comment: Yes, ExecuteScalar only returns the first value of the first row. Fetch will return a collection. Ok, I think I know what is it. I'll write an answer for you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Took me a little while to understand what was happening here.

The `Fetch<T>` runs a query and returns the result set as a typed list. Straight from the docs.

You will likely need to honour the typed part of this.

Hopefully, the following demonstrates what is happening.

```
public class TypedReturn { 
   public string recid { get; set; }
}

var sql = new Sql()
    .Append(@"; WITH _in (lastname, firstname, birthdate, description, dencounter) AS (
                VALUES ( UPPER(@0), UPPER(@1), @2::date, LOWER(@3), @4::date  )
                )
                  DELETE FROM dx d
                    USING _in n
                   JOIN patients pt ON (pt.lastname, pt.firstname, pt.birthdate) = (n.lastname, n.firstname, n.birthdate)
                  JOIN disease z ON (z.description = n.description)
                  WHERE (d.patient_recid, d.disease_recid, d.dposted)=(pt.recid, z.recid, n.dencounter)
               RETURNING d.recid;", lastName, firstName, birthDate, description, tencounter);

List<TypedReturn> returnValues = db.Fetch<TypedReturn>(sql);

foreach(var returnValue in returnValues) 
{
    Console.WriteLine(returnValue.recid);
}
```

Or you could use `dynamic`, which you would do like so

```
var sql = new Sql()
    .Append(@"; WITH _in (lastname, firstname, birthdate, description, dencounter) AS (
                VALUES ( UPPER(@0), UPPER(@1), @2::date, LOWER(@3), @4::date  )
                )
                  DELETE FROM dx d
                    USING _in n
                   JOIN patients pt ON (pt.lastname, pt.firstname, pt.birthdate) = (n.lastname, n.firstname, n.birthdate)
                  JOIN disease z ON (z.description = n.description)
                  WHERE (d.patient_recid, d.disease_recid, d.dposted)=(pt.recid, z.recid, n.dencounter)
               RETURNING d.recid;", lastName, firstName, birthDate, description, tencounter);

List<dynamic> returnValues = db.Fetch<dynamic>(sql);

foreach(var returnValue in returnValues) 
{
    Console.WriteLine(returnValue.recid);
}
```

Comment: Great answer! dynamic was hard to work with (for me), so I adapted your first answer with: private class TypedReturn
        {
            public int? recid { get; set; }
        } .  Is there an easier way then:  return db.Fetch<TypedReturn>(sql).Select(i => i.recid); ??

Comment: There's no easy way. I could probably add an `ExecuteScalarList<T>`. If you add an [issue](https://github.com/CollaboratingPlatypus/PetaPoco/issues), I'll take a look